# task on java.util concurrent. Multithreading problems with polling from BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I've received a task about java.util.concurrent package of java. I've made it almost totally, but there is some bug or mistake. When the queue is empty and operator waits for 5 seconds method poll should retrieve null and pass it to the operator and operator goes home. But it doesn't happen. It retrieves null but doesn't pass it to the operator. Sorry for my English.)

```
public class Client extends Thread {

public CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);

private boolean waiting;

private final Random random=new Random();


public boolean isWaiting() {
    return waiting;
}

public void setWaiting(boolean isWaiting) {
    this.waiting = isWaiting;
}

private static final Logger LOGGER;


static {
    LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
    new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure("log4j.xml",
            LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}

private int limitTime=new Random().nextInt(5000);

public void run(){
    ClientQueue.enqueueClient(this);
    while(waiting){
        if (random.nextBoolean()){
            try {
                latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (!waiting) return;
                ClientQueue.removeFromQueue(this);
                reportTiredToWait();
                sleep(random.nextInt(1000)+500);
                ClientQueue.enqueueClient(this);
                reportDecidedToCallAgain();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Exception");
            }
        }
    }
}

public Client(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.waiting=true;
}

private void reportTiredToWait(){
    LOGGER.info("Client "+getName()+" was tired to wait and decided to hang up");
}

private void reportDecidedToCallAgain(){
    LOGGER.info("Client "+getName()+" decided to call again");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Client "+getName();
}
```

}

```
    public class ClientQueue {

    private static final Logger LOGGER;


    static {
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClientQueue.class);
        new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure("log4j.xml",
                LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }

    private static ClientQueue instance;

    private BlockingQueue<Client> queue;

    public static void printQueue(){
        System.out.println("LIST OF CLIENTS:");
        for (Client client :ClientQueue.getInstance().queue){
            System.out.println("CLIENT "+client.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("END OF LIST OF CLIENTS:");

    }

    private static ClientQueue getInstance()
    {
        if ( instance == null )
        {
            instance = new ClientQueue();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ClientQueue()
    {
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Client>();
    }

    public static void enqueueClient(Client client){
        getInstance().queue.add(client);
        reportClientEnqueued(client.getName());
    }

    public static void removeFromQueue(Client client){
        ClientQueue.getInstance().queue.remove(client);
        reportClientDeletedFromQueue(client.getName());
    }

    public static Client pollFirst(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException{
        Client client=null;
            client = getInstance().queue.poll(time, timeUnit);

        if (client!=null){
            reportClientRetrievedFromQueue(client.getName());
        }
        return client;
    }

    private static  void reportClientEnqueued(String name){
        LOGGER.info("Client "+name+" was put on the waiting list");
    }

    private static void reportClientDeletedFromQueue(String name){
        LOGGER.info("Client " +name+" was deleted from waiting list");
    }

    private static void reportClientRetrievedFromQueue(String name){
        LOGGER.info("Client " +name+" was retrieved from waiting list");
    }

}

    public class Operator extends Thread{

    private static final Logger LOGGER;

    static {
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Operator.class);
        new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure("log4j.xml",
                LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }

    private boolean running;

    public Operator(String name){
        super(name);
        running= true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){
                Client client=null;
                try {
                    client = ClientQueue.pollFirst(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (client!=null){
                    String clientName=client.getName();
                    reportOperatorReceivedCall(clientName);
                    try {
                        client.setWaiting(false);
                        client.latch.countDown();
                        sleep(10000);
                        reportOperatorFinishedConversation(clientName);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        LOGGER.error(e);
                    }
                } else{
                    reportOperatorFinishedHisWork();
                    running=false;
                }
        }
    }

    private void reportOperatorReceivedCall(String name){
        LOGGER.info("Operator "+getName()+" received call from Client "+name);
    }

    private void reportOperatorFinishedConversation(String name){
        LOGGER.info("Operator "+getName()+" finished conversation with Client "+name);
    }

    private void reportOperatorFinishedHisWork(){
        LOGGER.info("Operator "+getName()+" finished his work for today, he is too tired and decided to go home.");
    }


}

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);


        LinkedList<Client> clientList = new LinkedList<Client>();
        clientList.add(new Client("Vasya"));
        clientList.add(new Client("Tanya"));
        clientList.add(new Client("Petya"));
        clientList.add(new Client("Kolya"));
        clientList.add(new Client("Elena"));
        clientList.add(new Client("Anna"));
        for(int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
            executor.schedule(clientList.get(i),  i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        LinkedList<Operator> operatorList = new LinkedList<Operator>();
        operatorList.add(new Operator("Bob"));
        operatorList.add(new Operator("Sandra"));
        operatorList.add(new Operator("John"));
        for(int i = 0; i < operatorList.size(); i++) {
            executor.schedule(operatorList.get(i), 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon in `ClientQueue.pollFirst`. Here it is corrected:

```
public static Client pollFirst(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException{
    Client client=null;
        client = getInstance().queue.poll(time, timeUnit);

    if (client!=null) { // removed semicolon from this line
        reportClientRetrievedFromQueue(client.getName());
    }
    return client;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting the semicolon. But it doesn't solve the problem. I made my question more clear.